# PyLab title/legend labels with multiple line of text

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to make multiple lines of text inside a title/legend label in pylab?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, just use the \n escape sequence inside it.

```
element = pylab.plot(range(100))
pylab.legend([element],[ "first line \n second line"])
```